# How to enable color for PHP CLI?

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line-interface

How do I enable the colors for output of CLI?
The below one is, running on Ubuntu.

[image]

If you see the screenshot, obviously the colors is enabled for terminal. And, if I call `echo`, it doesn't colorize the result, but if I use `echo -e`, it colorizes. 
I checked manual page of `echo`, and `-e` means **enable interpretation of backslash escapes**
How can I enable this option for PHP CLI?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

First we use an escape character so we can actually define a output color. This is done with `\033` (\e). Then we open the color statement with `[31m`. Red in this case.

The "some colored text" will be the text outputted in a different color. And after that we have to close the color statement with `\033[0m`.

```
php -r 'echo "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";'
```

[ref 1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization)

[ref 2](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

[image]

Comment: yes, it worked after I replaced `\e` with `033`. Thank you.

Comment: and you can learn more [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

Comment: Or do not rely on `echo`'s sequences, and instead directly generate the ANSI sequences within the string using ANSI-C quoting: `$'\e[31mblah blah\e[0m`. This way you don't need to remember `\033` or whatever.

Comment: single quotes will not work by the way :) use double quotes

Comment: +1 super helpful. FYI if anyone else needs [help looking up color codes](https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-colors/).

Comment: any way to get this to work when a PHP script is run via tty? Works from CLI normally but not in any git bash instances running in embedded terminals. (other commands show colours tho in the same setup)

Comment: `NOTE²: The “\e[0m” sequence removes all attributes (formatting and colors). It can be a good idea to add it at the end of each colored text. ;)` - if you don't close it everything you output afterwards - even different `echo` will still be in last color.

Answer (score 30):

For lazier

```
function colorLog($str, $type = 'i'){
    switch ($type) {
        case 'e': //error
            echo "\033[31m$str \033[0m\n";
        break;
        case 's': //success
            echo "\033[32m$str \033[0m\n";
        break;
        case 'w': //warning
            echo "\033[33m$str \033[0m\n";
        break;  
        case 'i': //info
            echo "\033[36m$str \033[0m\n";
        break;      
        default:
        # code...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer

Comment: this would make a good helper function, also the time would be nice,  $date = date('h:i:s', time());

Comment: You should write an open source project for this :P

Comment: @supersan it's more convenient, work done for you, it's for lazy people, not a "better answer". Accepted answer actually explains what's happening.

Answer (score 12):

After doing some experiments, I made these codes:

```php
function formatPrint(array $format=[],string $text = '') {
  $codes=[
    'bold'=>1,
    'italic'=>3, 'underline'=>4, 'strikethrough'=>9,
    'black'=>30, 'red'=>31, 'green'=>32, 'yellow'=>33,'blue'=>34, 'magenta'=>35, 'cyan'=>36, 'white'=>37,
    'blackbg'=>40, 'redbg'=>41, 'greenbg'=>42, 'yellowbg'=>44,'bluebg'=>44, 'magentabg'=>45, 'cyanbg'=>46, 'lightgreybg'=>47
  ];
  $formatMap = array_map(function ($v) use ($codes) { return $codes[$v]; }, $format);
  echo "\e[".implode(';',$formatMap).'m'.$text."\e[0m";
}
function formatPrintLn(array $format=[], string $text='') {
  formatPrint($format, $text); echo "\r\n";
}

//Examples:
formatPrint(['blue', 'bold', 'italic','strikethrough'], "Wohoo");
formatPrintLn(['yellow', 'italic'], " I'm invicible");
formatPrintLn(['yellow', 'bold'], "I'm invicible");
```

Just copy and paste the code above and... Enjoy :)

Comment: Fantastic helper function

Answer (score 2):

A Cleaner solution in the form a reusable class.

PHP Class:

```
class CLI
{

    // this method requires one variable. the second, color, is optional
    function cout_color($content, $color=null)
    {
        
        // if a color is set use the color set.
        if(!empty($color))
        {
            // if our color string is not a numeric value
            if(!is_numeric($color))
            {
                    //lowercase our string value.
                    $c = strtolower($color);
                
            }
            else
                {   
                    // check if our color value is not empty.
                    if(!empty($color))
                    {
                        
                        $c = $color;
                    
                    }
                    else
                        { 
                            // no color was set so lets pick a random one...
                            $c = rand(1,14);
                            
                        }
                    
                }
                
        }
        else    // no color argument was passed, so lets pick a random one w00t
            { 
                
                $c = rand(1,14);
                            
            }
        
        $cheader = '';
        $cfooter = "\033[0m";
        
        // let check which color code was used so we can then wrap our content.
        switch($c)
        {
                    
            case 1:
            case 'red':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[31m";

            break;
            
            case 2:
            case 'green':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[32m";

            break;

            case 3:
            case 'yellow':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[33m";

            break;
            
            case 4:
            case 'blue':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[34m";

            break;
            
            case 5:
            case 'magenta':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[35m";

            break;
            
            case 6:
            case 'cyan':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[36m";

            break;
            
            case 7:
            case 'light grey':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[37m";

            break;
            
            case 8:
            case 'dark grey':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[90m";

            break;
            
            case 9:
            case 'light red':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[91m";

            break;
            
            case 10:
            case 'light green':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[92m";

            break;
            
            case 11:
            case 'light yellow':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[93m";

            break;
            
            case 12:
            case 'light blue':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[94m";

            break;
            
            case 13:
            case 'light magenta':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[95m";

            break;
            
            case 14:
            case 'light cyan':
                
                // color code header.
                $cheader .= "\033[92m";

            break;
            
        }
          
        // wrap our content.
        $content = $cheader.$content.$cfooter;
        
        //return our new content.
        return $content;
        

    }
      
     

}
```

Basic Usage:

```
//create a new object
$cli = new CLI();

//example string
$text = 'Success!';

//color via class color id
$text = $cli->cout_color($text, 2);

//color via string name
//$text = $cli->cout_color($text, 'green');

//for random color, ignore the second parameter.:
//$text = $cli->cout_color($text);

echo $text;
```

Modify to your project requirements. Good luck.